Is it possible to configure serilog to accept specifc logging, even if the severity is below the sink's minimum severity?
This is how my logging in Asp.Net is configured:
    _ = pServiceCollection.AddSerilog((serviceProvider, loggerConfiguration)
                                          => loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(pConfiguration)
                                                                .ReadFrom.Services(serviceProvider)
                                                                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                                                                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: LogMessageTemplate,
                                                                                 formatProvider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                                                .WriteTo.File(path: logFilePath,
                                                                              outputTemplate: LogMessageTemplate,
                                                                              rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                                                                              retainedFileCountLimit: 30,
                                                                              formatProvider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                                                                .WriteTo.EventLog(source: CommonConstants.ProductName,
                                                                                  manageEventSource: true,
                                                                                  restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Warning,
                                                                                  formatProvider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

Only Warning or higher will be logged to the event log (because of restrictedToMinimumLevel)
But there is one type of Info level logging that I want to log to the event log, too.
I tried out appending this limitation (Filter.ByIncludingOnly) and using a "category", but unfortunately, this will be applied to all sinks. I want it only for the event log sink.
.WriteTo.File(path: logFilePath,
              outputTemplate: LogMessageTemplate,
              rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
              retainedFileCountLimit: 30,
              formatProvider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
.WriteTo.EventLog(source: CommonConstants.ProductName,
                  manageEventSource: true,
                  restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Warning,
                  formatProvider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
.Filter.ByIncludingOnly(e =>
                            (e.Level == LogEventLevel.Information &&
                             (e.Properties.ContainsKey("SourceContext") &&
                              e.Properties["SourceContext"].ToString().Contains(CommonConstants.ForceLoggingToEventLogCategory))) ||
                            e.Level >= LogEventLevel.Warning));

This was the other side:
var forcelogger = app.Services.GetService<ILoggerProvider>()!.CreateLogger(CommonConstants.ForceLoggingToEventLogCategory);
forcelogger.LogInformation("force hallo Welt");



Conclusion: I like the logging setup with Asp.Net logging and Serilog and want only warning and higher in the event log, but there are 2-3 exceptions. Is it possible to achieve this?

What is the actual logic behind the sink choice? You can specify additional sinks with the conditions you want to ensure specific messages (eg from specific categories, specific types) go to the Event log. The question itself sounds like an XY problem. What you wrote and what you ask are the assumed solution. It won't work, both .NET's and Serilog's ILogger are the interfaces used to create event messages, not the sinks themselves.

BTW please, please format the code to make it visible

"You can specify additional sinks with the conditions you want to ensure specific messages (eg from specific categories, specific types) go to the Event log." How can I do this?

Add more .WriteTo.EventLog calls. You can use .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource<MyClass>()) to filter by a specific source

Are you sure, this works? I'm quite sure, I have tried this yesterday, and it was applied to all sinks, instead of just the one.

Yes, it works if you apply it through a sub-logger. In the docs, this is shown in the the sub-loggers section right below Filter : .WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc         .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(...)         .WriteTo.File("log.txt"))

Thanks, that works. I did not solve it with such a "sub logger". I did not know about that technique.

As I wrote, I always get confused myself. That's not something I need to use very often (only 1-2 times per project) so I always forget it. By now, I've hit that wall enough times that I remember ....

You can create another sink with its own filter.
I always get tripped up by the syntax required to filter specific loggers too. The way the Fluent API works, you need to create a sub-logger to specify filters for individual loggers. Otherwise the filter apply to all sinks. That's the only way you can keep chaining calls.
The alternative would be to break the chain of calls and configure sinks in separate statements.
In this example, Information events generated by the AdminController source will be logged to the Event log.
.WriteTo.EventLog(source: CommonConstants.ProductName,
                  manageEventSource: true,
                  restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Warning,
                  formatProvider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
.WriteTo.Logger(lc => lc
        .Filter.ByIncludingOnly(Matching.FromSource<AdminController>())
        .WriteTo.EventLog(source: CommonConstants.ProductName,
                  manageEventSource: false,
                  restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information,
                  formatProvider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
);

